# onclick needs to be double clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

When using `onclick` in JavaScript to call the function `nowClicked()`, I need to click the object twice in order for the alert to show. Below is the code for my function.

```
function nowClicked() {

  $('.object').click(function() {

    $('.object').removeClass("clicked");
    var myClass = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(myClass);

    $(this).addClass("clicked");

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  });
};
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Please add all the relevant code (HTML and CSS) and edit your question to have that code inside of a "code snippet" so we can run and reproduce your issue as well as easily provide you with a working answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to put it inside another function,because `click` is itself handling a callback function.Remove the outer function `nowClicked` else remove the `$('.object').click(function() {`.In the second case you may to pass the `context` as a function argument.

```
$('.object').click(function() {
  $('.object').removeClass("clicked");
  var myClass = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(myClass);
  $(this).addClass("clicked");
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what happens the first time you click your button:

1. `nowClicked` is called because you've set it up on the button's `onclick`
2. `nowClicked` sets up a jQuery click handler for `.object`

The code *inside* the jQuery click handler only runs the *next* time you click on the button.

It looks like you are mixing up two ways of handling clicks -- one is using the `onclick` event, and the second is using jQuery. You need to pick one and stick to it instead of using both.